# Performance hit when persisting hundreds of millions of SQL Timestamp objects

Tags: java, sql, database, performance

During execution of a program that relies on the `oracle.sql` package  there is a large performance hit for persisting > 200 million Timestamps when compared to persisting the same number of longs.

[Basic Schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/62491)

Java to persist:

```
Collection<ARRAY> longs = new ArrayList<ARRAY>(SIZE);
Collection<ARRAY> timeStamps = new ArrayList<ARRAY>(SIZE);
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE;i++)  
{  
    longs.add(new ARRAY(description, connection, i));  
    timeStamps.add(new ARRAY(description,connection,new Timestamp(new Long(i)));
}  

Statement timeStatement = conn.createStatement();  
statement.setObject(1,timeStamps);  
statement.execute();   //5 minutes

Statement longStatement = conn.createStatement();  
statement.setObject(1,longs);  
statement.execute();  //1 minutes 15 seconds
```

My question is what does Oracle do to Timestamps that make them so awful to insert in a bulk manner?

Configuration:

```
64 bit RHEL 5  
jre 6u16  
ojdbc14.jar
64 GB dedicated to the JVM
```

**UPDATE**
  `java.sql.Timestamp` is being used

Comment: The fact that it's exactly 4x longer makes me think it performs 4 elementary operations while the long performs 1.

Comment: So the database does something extra behind the scenes to "help"? Is there a workaround that allows me to perform queries against a date range?

Answer (score 1):

Number takes 4 bytes, Timestamp takes 11 bytes. In addition, Timestamp has metadata associated with it. For each Timestamp, Oracle seems to compute the metadata and store with the field.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle timestamps are not stored as absolute value since epoc like a java.sql.Timestamp internally holds.  It's a big bitmask containing values for the various "human" fields, centuries, months, etc.

So each one of your nanosecond-since-epoch timestamps is getting parsed into a "human" date before storage.

Comment: I see.  Is there a work around?  Essentially the data gets queried on for date ranges.

Comment: Well, actually now that I read more closely, is that a java.sql.Timestamp or an oracle.sql.Timestamp?

Comment: using oracle.sql.Timestamp may be a big help then, it uses the oracle representation of the data in-memory in java, so it should convert to an insert statement faster (although unless your input is coming in a way that could be directly translated to oracle's bytes, you will ultimately incur the cost *somewhere*)

Comment: Well to be more clear the code in java uses the java.sql.timestamp the database is whatever Oracle treats a timestamp as.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Srini's post, for documentation on memory use by data type:

**Oracle Doc on Data Types:** http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21642/types.htm#autoId31 (includes memory size for Number and Timestamp)

The docs state that Number takes 5-22 bytes, Timestamp takes 11 bytes, Integer takes 4 bytes.

Also - to your point on querying against a date range - could you insert the dates as long values instead of timestamps and then use a stored procedure to convert when you are querying the data?  This will obviously impact the speed of the queries, so it could be kicking the problem down the road, but....  :)

Comment: Right, I decided to go for the use of timestamps in the database as I didnt want to do a conversion N times a minute by the nature of a distributed system.  Primarily because I do not believe that Oracle caches the result of a function.  If however the function result does get cached I may revisit that.

Comment: Not that I have great love for Oracle databases let alone writing functions to call in the DB, but it happens that Oracle 11g does in fact provide a capability to cache the result of your function. [See this article on how to set it up.](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=504)

Comment: I ended up going for the materialized view, since it is 10g